# Consolidating Contacts from Multiple Services

Tags: contacts

I'm looking for a good way to consolidate my many email/messenger contacts through my different accounts and services.  I'd like to have all my contacts in one place, or have them sync between all my different services so they are the same everywhere.  If possible, it should support Live Mail/Messenger, Google Contacts, and mobile syncing.

Windows Live Mail is great for accessing all your mail accounts, but the contacts viewer only works for contacts affiliated with that Live account.  I could go for the contacts folder built into Vista and above, but Live messenger doesn't access that so I would have a separate set of contacts for my IM account.

Is there software, or an online service, that can do this?
If this is asking to much, is there a proper solution to Live/Google Contacts bidirectional sync?

Comment: One option is to buy PalmPre or some Android based phone with HTC Sense UI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for something similar. I haven't gotten anything that exactly suits my needs yet, but you might wanna check out the following sites. None of them are easy to use as you have to run them on your own webserver.

- http://knowee.net/
- http://noserub.com/
- http://diso-project.org/

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I wouldn't mind running a local webserver, but I don't think these projects offer quite what I'm looking for.  A couple of them are very interesting though, and I'll keep an eye on them.

Thanks.

Comment: same problem here...they're not quite what I want. Soocial.com promised to deliver what I want, but I'm not quite sure its as good as it claims. It hasn't been able to merge say Anika Havdar in my phone contacts with anika.havdar@domain.com. Its not its fault though, it can't be sure I don't have 2 contacts with the same name. Best way out would be some way to export the data from facebook, which has all the right amounts of data correctly associated with the right person.

Comment: Here in the future, 1 link is to a Japanese fashion blog(?), 1 is dead, and the other looks like it died back in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can export vcf (contact card) file from most of these services, then import it on your other account. Google also offers Outlook specific file (which is also compatible with Live). What you should do is decide on a primary service (live/gmail etc) to always update your contacts. Then once a month/week do the export->import the contact file (vcf, csv etc).